# How do I write encoders/decoders for Thoth.Json in the SAFE Stack?

Tags: f#, elmish, safe-stack

I'm building an application using the SAFE Stack and I have a System.Uri in my model.
When I run my code I get an error in the console "Cannot generate autoencoder for System.Uri..."
My googling has got me to here so far

```
module CustomEncoders

open Thoth.Json
let uriEncoder (uri:System.Uri) = Encode.string (uri.ToString())

let uriDecoder = ????

let myExtraCoders =
    Extra.empty
    |> Extra.withCustom uriEncoder uriDecoder 


let modelEncoder = Encode.Auto.generateEncoder(extra = myExtraCoders)
let modelDecoder = Decode.Auto.generateDecoder(extra = myExtraCoders)
```

Then in my App.fs I add

```
|> Program.withDebuggerCoders CustomEncoders.modelEncoder CustomEncoders.modelDecoder
```

I think I have understood how to create an encoder but I have no idea how to write the decoder part.
I could obviously replace my System.Uri fields with string but that doesn't feel like the right solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [Decoder Type](https://github.com/thoth-org/Thoth.Json.Net/blob/master/src/Types.fs#L24), It has the following signature
`string -> JsonValue -> Result<'T, DecoderError>`

Where

- string: json path to select from the json value
- JsonValue: raw json to decode

And it either returns an `Ok<'T>` or `Error<DecoderError>`

So your uri Decoder will be as follows

```ml
let uriDecoder path (token: JsonValue) =
    let value = token.Value<string>()
    match System.Uri.TryCreate(value, System.UriKind.Absolute) with
    | (true, uri) -> Ok uri
    | (false, _) -> Error (path, BadPrimitive("Uri", token))
```

Comment: Thanks, I seem to be missing something? I get an error saying Value isn't a member of Object (looking at the source for Thoth.Json this makes sense since JsonValue appears to be an alias for obj? Am I missing a module open?

Comment: Replacing it with let value = token.ToString() works but I'd love to understand what the issue I was having with the code you proposed is (I'm very much an F# newbie)

Comment: Ah, I see, I was using `Thoth.Json.Net` which is the .NET native, yeah, using `token.ToString()` is probably the best way to go for you

Comment: Ahhh, I'm using it on the client side so I think I have to use Thoth.Json (if I'm understanding that right)

Comment: @DavidHayes Yes, that's correct. They have the same API but have completely different implementations